# Enviar imagen estática de mapa por correo electronico

Tags: php, google-maps, email, imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas a todos.

Al enviar un mail desde mi server, creado en PHP, a un usuario, intento incluir,embebido, una imagen de google map usando "Google Static Maps API" del siguiente modo:

```html
<td valign="top" style="text-align:center;">
  <img alt="Este correo es seguro. Esta imagen muestra la distancia entre quien te escribe y tú. 
Si no ves esta imagen es porque el proxy de google image aun no la ha escaneado.
 En unos minutos estara disponible." 
 style="width: 75%; border-radius: 25px;" 
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:green%7Clabel:D%7C40.4167754,-3.70379019&markers=color:red%7Clabel:M%7C41.3850639,2.17340349&path=40.4167754,-3.70379019%7C41.3850639,2.17340349&size=400x200&scale=2&language=es&key=MY_KEY/"/>
</td>
```

y no se visualiza la imagen, solo aparece el texto alternativo (véase adjunto).

Inspeccionando elementos del correo observo lo siguiente:

```html
<td valign="top" style="text-align:center">
<img alt="Este correo es seguro. Esta imagen muestra la distancia entre quien te escribe y tú. 
Si no ves esta imagen es porque el proxy de google image aun no la ha escaneado.
 En unos minutos estara disponible." 
style="width:75%;border-radius:25px" 
src="**https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/MRC1dOr95HyhqdWGnvSdbmSbfeLC0Gb5IIKlDs45mDHcQPGU-QKldB8vjmoE0C1lPFKORAA-xdEOXQshSiIJJOWna8LX3d_dKv2VrO2rtQibUFPJEB4Vu5L0OnVF29_VflGLR2t-3oEL42ShVlz9zJ7lPTchig5rfpoYydTon1WaHBx94RbJyCpYHwsyYF0CDS6FNOBaiDssVl4YJJ6VW1vHDy819wW2UeN0JE1xs2EoodokUN8fz9hRPR4qRgXvJ1CUjA4nDr0KNbSZDKZ10_LaTnQaXQJMUC69OdzkC3rSLWolNvQS4uXTfv2UYsweZG2viPrYBAu8rJDy92rQWaEXMVt7ndexjp4vGsWr3JSRkf5swE68vnRa1wPEMnCo0NmAR_4nSsXvtuaYrPZ02Fuz=s0-d-e1-ft#**https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:green%7Clabel:D%7C40.4167754,-3.70379019&amp;markers=color:red%7Clabel:M%7C41.3850639,2.17340349&amp;path=40.4167754,-3.70379019%7C41.3850639,2.17340349&amp;size=400x200&amp;scale=2&amp;language=es&amp;key=MY_KEY/" 
class="CToWUd"></td>
```

Según me he informado, Gmail esta almacenando en cache todas las imágenes que van a correos electrónicos, por lo que entiendo que hasta que no sea analizada y almacenada en cache de Google no podrá verla el usuario.

El caso es que recién llegado el mail no se ve, hasta pasado unos minutos que pueden variar desde 5 minutos hasta 20 minutos, y es cuando aparece la foto en el correo, pero igualmente si entro mas tarde al mismo correo, 30 minutos,  vuelve a desaparecer la imagen.

Mi pregunta es ¿Estoy haciendo algo erróneamente o Google funciona así y debo tomar otras alternativas?

Gracias por su atención, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado!! He probado a almacenar la imagen en mi servidor antes de enviarla embebida en el correo y chapó!! a resuelto el problema!!

```js
$src_mapa = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:green|label:".$label_origen."|".$lat_origen.",".$lng_origen."&markers=color:red|label:".$label_destino."|".$lat_destino.",".$lng_destino."&path=".$lat_origen.",".$lng_origen."|".$lat_destino.",".$lng_destino."&size=400x200&scale=2&language=es&key=MY_KEY";

    $time = time();
    $desFolder = 'ruta/';
    $imageName = 'google_map_'.$time.'_'.$datos_de['id'].'_'.$datos_para['id'].'.png';
    $imagePath = $desFolder.$imageName;
    file_put_contents($imagePath,file_get_contents($src_mapa));
```

```html
'<td valign="top" style="text-align:center;">
  <img alt="Este correo es seguro. 
Esta imagen muestra la distancia entre quien te escribe y tú." 
style="width: 75%; border-radius: 25px;"
src="'.$url_serverPHP.$imagePath.'"/>
</td>'.
```

Comment: Un pequeño apunte: creo que sería mejor que enviaras la imagen en el propio correo, embebida como un base64, así no tendrías que guardar la imagen en el servidor, y si por un casual la borras, el correo se podrá seguir visualizando